# C++Builder specific way to handle control messages without subclassing?

Tags: c++builder

I seem to recall some C++Builder specific method of handling messages from controls without having to actually subclass the control.   Does such an option exist to do so?  Or does C++Builder have a special method you can use to easily subclass controls.

In this case I want to handle **WM_COPY** from a TEdit control so it doesn't just happen, I need to handle it.

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

.h:

```
class TMyForm : public TForm
{
  // ...
  private:
    virtual void __fastcall MyEditWndProc(TMessage &Message);
    System::Classes::TWndMethod  m_PriorMyEditWndProc;
  // ...
};
```

.cpp:

```
__fastcall TMyForm::TMyForm(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    m_PriorMyEditWndProc=MyEdit->WindowProc;
    MyEdit->WindowProc=MyEditWndProc;

}

void __fastcall TMyForm::MyEditWndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    if (Message.Msg == WM_COPY) {
      // ...
      return;
    }
    /* removed per comment
    else if (Message.Msg == WM_DESTROY) {
        MyEdit->WindowProc=m_PriorMyEditWndProc;
    } */
    m_PriorMyEditWndProc(Message);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to restore the `TEdit`'s original `WindowProc` on `WM_DESTROY`. In fact, you shouldn't do that, because the VCL can recreate its HWNDs dynamically during the UI's lifetime, which will generate `WM_DESTROY`s even though the app is still running, and if that happens then you will lose your message handler.